# Validation error on logout in Laravel

Tags: php, authentication, laravel

After upgrading to latest version of Laravel, I get an error message when I try to log out after being logged in.

My validation looks like this (I've put this in the User model):

```
public $errors;

protected static $rules = array(
    'name'       => 'required',
    'email'      => 'required,email',
    'company_id' => 'required,integer'
);

public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::saved(function()
    {
        // Cache::forget('query.user.all');
    });

    static::saving(function($model)
    {
        return $model->validate();
    });
}

public function validate()
{
    $v = Validator::make($this->getAttributes(), static::$rules);

    if ($v->fails())
    {
        $this->errors = $v->messages();
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

I think it's because the form input doesn't exist when logging out, so the validation fails. Is there a way to split the save function into one for logging in, and one for logging out?

[image: Screen shot of error message]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says `validateRequired,email` does not exist.

Thats because your validation rules dont look to be correct. You should spilt them with piping like `|` or you can put them as separate elements of an array.

Change

```
protected static $rules = array(
    'name'       => 'required',
    'email'      => 'required,email',
    'company_id' => 'required,integer'
);
```

to

```
protected static $rules = array(
    'name'       => 'required',
    'email'      => 'required|email',
    'company_id' => 'required|integer'
);
```

or

```
protected static $rules = array(
    'name'       => 'required',
    'email'      => array('required', 'email'),
    'company_id' => array('required', 'integer')
);
```